# Hashing wordlist with big input output files in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, hash, output

I'm a beginner in coding and am trying to build a script that takes a txt file as an input, hash it and output to another txt file containing "string:hashedstring" in each line of it. The code is working properly. The problem I am facing now is that if the input file is big, it will consume all RAM and kill it. I tried to use chunks, but couldn't figure out how to use it with multiline input and output.
Any suggestions regarding other parts of the code other than the main subject here is very welcome, since I am just starting on this. Thanks.

```
import argparse
import hashlib
import os
import sys

def sofia_hash(msg):
    h = ""
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    msg_md5 = m.digest()
    for i in range(8):
        n = (msg_md5[2*i] + msg_md5[2*i+1]) % 0x3e
        if n > 9:
            if n > 35:
                n += 61
            else:
                n += 55
        else:
            n += 0x30
        h += chr(n)
    return h

top_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Sofiamass')
top_parser.add_argument('input', action="store", type=argparse.FileType('r', encoding='utf8'), help="Set input file")
top_parser.add_argument('output', action="store", help="Set output file")
args = top_parser.parse_args()


sofiainput = args.input.read().splitlines()
a = 0
try:
    while a < len(sofiainput):
        target_sofiainput = sofiainput[a]
        etarget_sofiainput = (target_sofiainput).encode('utf-8')
        try:
            sofia_pass = sofia_hash(target_sofiainput)
            x = True
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print ("\n[---]exiting now[---]")
        if x == True:
            with open(args.output, 'a') as sofiaoutput:
                sofiaoutput.write(str(target_sofiainput) + ":" + str(sofia_pass) + "\n")
        elif x == False:
           print('error')

        a += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\n[---]exiting now[---]")
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file with the *open* command, it creates a object called file handler. So, when you do:

```
with open('filepath.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

it only keeps the current line you are using in the RAM, thus achieving your objective to use as little as RAM as possible.